# Up-to-date recommendations for yocto build host version

Tags: yocto

Because the documentation recommends Ubuntu 15.10 as a yocto build host, we went to considerable effort to set this up, only to find that Bitbake still tells us that this is not a supported version.

What is the latest recommended Ubuntu version, please? I'm thinking we may as go with the latest LTS.

Comment: Can you please add that error message here?

Comment: It was:
```
WARNING: Host distribution "ubuntu-18.04" has not been validated with this
version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures.
It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Warrior Yocto version, you can use Ubuntu 18.04 as stated [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#detailed-supported-distros). For older Yocto version, you'll need an older host distribution due to GCC support.

Anyway, I suggest you to build Yocto within a Docker environment, for example [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/gmacario/build-yocto/dockerfile).